# Decimal number in text field

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get a decimal number from a text field. It only can be a decimal number but if I enter something like 'o,5', than the bullets will spawn a lot faster than every 0.5 second.

My code:

```
@IBAction func enemyBulletDelayClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissKeyboard()

    let correctNumber = enemyBulletDelayText.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
    enemyBulletDelay = Double(correctNumber!)!
    enemyBulletDelayText.text = ""
}
```

(I'm converting each ',' to a '.' for the decimal numbers.)
Otherwise it would give me an error.

Comment: The proper way to convert a user-entered decimal number into an `NSNumber` (then `Double`) is to use an `NSNumberFormatter`/`NumberFormatter`.

Comment: And avoid all of those `!`. They are crashes waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ? you need to unwrap, not put !

There are a bunch of ways to remove . afterwards. Pick whatever you want. This is more focused on the process of what you're doing and then you can decide on using NSNumberFormatter or whatever you want to do.

```
guard let enemyBulletDelayString = enemyBulletDelayText.text? else {
    //put whatever you want to do here if this check doesn't pass
    return
}

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = numberFormatter.Style.decimal

if let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.number(from: enemyBulletDelayString) {
  enemySpawnDelay = formattedNumber.doubleValue
} else {
  numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ","
  if let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.number(from: enemyBulletDelayString) {
  enemySpawnDelay = formattedNumber.doubleValue
  }
}
```

This should work with what you want to do.

Comment: There's probably little reason to try both decimal separators. A user in a given locale is only going to enter numbers in their usual format. And this will be helped if the decimal keypad is being used which will only show the proper separator.

Comment: Thanks for helping but if I use this, it'll always give 0.0 instead of the number in the text field.

Comment: remove my var enemyBulletDelay variable at the, I was just putting it there as an example. It looks like you already have an enemySpawnDelay variable, so set that to formattedNumber.doubleValue.

Comment: I've edited my code to set your variable.... I saw your code above that you said worked. Remember the guard statement that I added, that is to unwrap "enemySpawnDelayText.text" in case there are any failures with accessing that text. You should never have any ! anywhere(there are less common instances in which you can definitely use them, but don't until you understand them). You should unwrap anything with a ?.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use this code and it worked!

Code:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal

enemySpawnDelay = (formatter.number(from: enemySpawnDelayText.text!)?.doubleValue)!
```